Why is my material not showing up? (node connection red)
I'm working on a new personal project and encountered an issue I haven't faced before. I'm creating some CGI makeup using a human model (built with the Facebuilder addon, not sure if that's relevant).
However, when I added a sphere to my environment, the node connection turned red and the sphere's material doesn't seem to change. In the viewport's material preview, the sphere appears pink, which I believe indicates that there's no material assigned to it.


What am I doing wrong?

The input and output sockets on each node are color coded to indicate the type of data that they receive. Green means Shader, Yellow means RGBA values. Gray means single Float etc. You're trying to connect a Shader input into another shaders RGB color input.

THANK YOU! Such a silly mistake but could've taken me a while to identify. I just removed the Principal BSDF and connected Glass BSDF directly to Surface which solved the issue.

If you want the sphere to have a glass material, you can plug the Glass BSDF directly into the Material Output > Surface.  You could also delete the Glass BSDF and set the Transmission > Weight to 1 on the Principled BSDF.
